# Border container create generic mouseOver function

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I try to create a function to change border property of border container.
To do that I create a function for each border container on my MXML.

But I'd to code better and to do a generic function.

Today my function is:

```
protected function bcContact_mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
bcContact.setStyle("borderVisible",true);
bcContact.setStyle("borderWeight",2);
bcContact.setStyle("borderColor",'#000099');
}
```

bcContact is one border container Id.

I try to replace bcContact by this but it doesn't work.

Can you help me to solve this beginner mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the BorderContainer class (in Flash Builder, put in BorderContainer in the "Super class" text field)

Your class will look something like this:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import spark.components.BorderContainer;
package com.extensions.containers {

    class MyBorderContainer {

        function MyBorderContainer() {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, changeStyle);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, undoStyle);
        }

        private function changeStyle(e:MouseEvent):void {
            this.setStyle("borderVisible",true);
            this.setStyle("borderWeight",2);
            this.setStyle("borderColor",'#000099');
        }

        private function undoStyle(e:MouseEvent):void {
            this.setStyle("borderVisible",false);
            this.setStyle("borderWeight",0);
            this.setStyle("borderColor",'#000000');
        }
    }
}
```

This class will need to be in the file `src/com/extensions/containers/MyBorderContainer.as`

Then use this in your mxml as

```
<containers:MyBorderContainer>

</containers:MyBorderContainer>
```

where the namespace `containers` is set to point to `com/extensions/containers`

Comment: Thanks for this idea but it doesn't works. Indeed it's like eventlistener doesn't work.Do you know why

Comment: Ok I found where is the mistake. Indeed I create a class extend border Container and after I created an skin where host component is MyBorderContainer. In this case it doesn't work! But if I use MyBorderContainer without skin It works fine. thanks

Answer (score 2):

U can use `event.CurrentTraget` and then use the compare functions, compare with ids and do the settings.